# An inequality regarding expectation of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be positive-valued, well-behaved random variables. Further, let $g(\cdot) \ge 0$ and $f(\cdot)\ge 0$ be two functions and $E(\cdot)$ denotes expectation operator. 
I am trying to prove the following relationship
\begin{equation*}
E(f(X))E(Y^2g(Y))+E(X^2f(X))E(g(Y)) \ge 2E(Xf(X))E(Yg(Y)).
\end{equation*}

This is valid when both $X$ and $Y$ follow a Bernoulli distribution. I want to extend the assertion to general continuous random variables.

I have asked this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203559/an-inequality-regarding-expectation-of-random-variables), too. But it is found off-topic. One comment, though, suggests some hint: Divide by $Ef(X)Eg(Y)$. Treat $f(X)/Ef(X)$ and $g(Y)/Eg(Y)$ as Radon-Nikodym derivative. Bound from above the right side by sum of squares. Then apply Cauchy-Shwartz.

My problem is that I am not sure what Radon-Nikodym derivative is. When, I apply the hint what I get is the following:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{E(f(X))E(Y^2g(Y))} {E(f(X))E(g(Y))} + \frac {E(X^2f(X))E(g(Y))}{E(f(X))E(g(Y))} \ge \frac {2E(Xf(X))E(Yg(Y))} {E(f(X))E(g(Y))},
\end{equation*}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
\frac{E(Y^2g(Y))} {E(g(Y))} + \frac {E(X^2f(X))}{E(f(X))} \ge \frac {2E(Xf(X))E(Yg(Y))} {E(f(X))E(g(Y))}.
\end{equation*}

Now, there should be some $f(X)/Ef(X)$ to be treated as Radon-Nikodym derivative but I do not see any.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are $Y$ and $X$ independent?

Comment: Yes, in my case $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but I guess the above result should be obtained for even dependent random variables. Thanks!

Comment: Well I am not sure but for independent case it is easy to prove. See my answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Let's redefine $Y$ and $X$ to $\tilde Y$ and $\tilde X$ so that 
$$
E( \tilde Y^n )=E(Y ^n g(Y))/E(g(Y))\\
E( \tilde X^n )=E(X ^n f(X))/E(f(X))\\
$$
Since $g(\ )/E(g(Y))$ and $f(\ )/E(f(X))$ are densities with respect to the distributions of $Y$ and $X$ respectively, this is possible.
Then 
$$
E((\tilde Y-\tilde X)^2)=E(\tilde Y^2)+E(\tilde X^2)-2E(\tilde Y)E(\tilde X)\ge 0
$$
Getting back to original $Y$ and $X$ you get your inequality.

PS: if $\mu_{Y,X}$ is the probability distribution of $(Y,X)$ then 
$$
\nu_Y(A)=\int_A g(y)E(g(Y))^{-1}d\mu_Y(y)\\
\nu_X(A)=\int_A f(x)E(f(X))^{-1}d\mu_X(x)
$$
are the probability distributions of $\tilde Y$ and $\tilde X$ respectively.

REMARK. 
It was assumed that $E(f(X))>0$ and $E(g(Y))>0$. In the vanished case when $E(f(X))=0$ or $E(g(Y))=0$ the result follows immediately.

REMARK 2. I used the fact that $\tilde X,\tilde Y$ are independent assuming that $X,Y$ are independent. Indeed if $X,Y$ are independent then for any measurable $z(x,y)$
$$
\int_{A\times B} z(x,y)d\mu =\int_Ad\mu_x \int_B z(x,y)d\mu_y
$$
But then
$$
\int_{A\times B} z(x,y)g(y) f(x)d\mu =\int_A f(x)d\mu_x \int_B z(x,y) g(y)d\mu_y=\int_{A\times B } z(x,y) d\nu
$$

Comment: Thanks! This is the exact thing I was looking for! Much appreciated!

Comment: I tried to correct as many misprints as I could. Remain the independence considerations, which are not dealt with at present and should be reworded. For example one should *assume* (and one should show that one can assume) that $\tilde X$ and $\tilde Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks Did. Your remark is important.Probably we can deduct it from independence of $X,Y$, however I don't see it immediately and may be it is even wrong.

Comment: Well, I think I proved that independence of $(X,Y)$ implies independence of $(\tilde X,\ tilde Y)$